# Manage a multilingual iTunes library?

Tags: itunes, music, internationalization

I just imported a huge music library to iTunes.

This library contains plenty tracks that are already in my library, but the info is in a different language, my question is, is there a way to have the file info multilingual, so I'll be able to merge the files while keeping the info in both languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Every field is part of the songs [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) (or meta tag) and only one field can exist at any given time. A song can only have one track name, one genre, one composer, one album title, and so on:

[image]

Whether you set the name of the song, for example, to English, or some other language, it doesn't matter as it would require *two* distinct fields for one ID3 entry, and that is not supported in the metadata container.

This is not a limitation of iTunes, but of the songs container.

Comment: Thanks. What about specifying multiple artists, is this possible? I know it is in WMP (Contributing artists).

Comment: You can see the list of supported tags here: http://www.assistanttools.com/articles/id3v2-tags.shtml. You can also view what iTunes can display by right clicking a column (pulling down a listview of them all). You can fill in a field with anything you like. So you could put the English name of the artist under "artist" and the alternate under "album artist" for example